# unserialize array in Delphi

Tags: php, arrays, delphi, serialization

Is there any function in Delphi like "unserialize()" in PHP?

The array that I have is in string format like this:

> a:6:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:2:{s:3:"qty";i:1;s:1
>   5:"super_attribute";a:2:{i:234;s:4:"2047";i:237;s:
>   4:"4312";}}s:15:"attributes_info";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:
>   5:"label";s:6:"Taglia";s:5:"value";s:6:"6
>   anni";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:9:"TIPOLOGIA";s:5:"v
>   alue";s:25:"Completo + Pallone
>   Adidas";}}s:11:"simple_name";s:78:"Maglia Bacca Milan Carlos Ufficiale
>   2015 2016 Completo Pallone Jersey AC
>   MILAN";s:10:"simple_sku";s:4:"-148";s:20:"product_calculations";i:1;s:13:"shipmen
>   t_type";i:0;}

Thank you

Comment: Yes there are such functions. Perhaps not ones that use the PHP format. Why not use a standard like JSON?

Comment: I receive this string from an API function, so I can't modify the string's format

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any function in Delphi like "unserialize()" in PHP?

There is nothing in the Delphi runtime library that can operate directly on a the output from PHP [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). That function uses a bespoke format that is not standardised. In an ideal world you would use a widely accepted standard like JSON. Indeed PHP has support for JSON and if the serialization was instead performed with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it would be simple to deserialize in Delphi or indeed any other mainstream language.

You will need to take one of the following options to solve your problem:

1. Change the code that generates the text to use a standard format such as JSON.
2. Transcode the text, using a PHP engine, to a standard format such as JSON. You would do that with `json_encode(unserialize(...))`.
3. Write, or find existing, Delphi code that parses and deserializes the text produced by `serialize()`.

FWIW, any API that hands you the output of `serialize()` is badly designed and one might consider it prudent to look for an alternative.

Comment: I completely agree with David, using JSON between PHP and Delphi is a charm, just wanted to add a reference to this this Delphi JSON library that made my life easy. It should work from XE 3 onward. https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject